# Julia: how do I convert a symbolic expression to a function?

Tags: julia, sympy

I have created a symbolic expression using the SymPy package (https://github.com/jverzani/SymPy.jl). I want to now find the roots of that expression using the Roots package (https://github.com/JuliaLang/Roots.jl). However, I cannot figure out how to use the `fzeros` method for finding the roots, since this can only be applied on an object with the type `Function` rather than `Sym`, which is the type of my expression.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do. I create a symbolic `"x"` and a symbolic expression `sin(x)`. Now lets try to find the zeros of `sin(x)` between the values -10 and 10:

```
using SymPy
x = sym"x"
expr = sin(x)
using Roots
fzeros(expr,-10,10)
```

Here's the error:

```
ERROR: `fzeros` has no method matching fzeros(::Sym, ::Int64, ::Int64)
```

How do I convert an expression with `Sym` type to `Function` type, so I can find the roots?

Answer (score 4):

[UPDATE: The discussion below has been superseded in many cases by the recently introduced `lambdify` function. The call `lambdify(expr)` creates a julia function that does not call back into SymPy to evaluate, so should be much faster. It should work for most, but certainly not all, expressions.]

It is a two step process:

```
convert(Function, expr)
```

will return a function of the free variables, `x`, in your case. However, the function values are still symbolic and can't be used with `fzeros`. The inputs can be guessed, but the type of the return value is another story. However, coercing to float will work in this case:

```
fzeros(x -> float(convert(Function, expr)), -10, 10)
```

(You could also do this with `a -> float(replace(expr, x, a))`.)

For this simple example `solve(expr)` will also work, but in general, the `findroot` function in `SymPy` is not exposed, so numeric root solving via `SymPy` isn't a workaround without some effort by the end-users.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, forgot about that, `nsolve(expr, x0)` will work to find a single zero. The `fzeros` function in the original question is a bit of hack, which tries to find all the simple zeros in the specified interval. This is more along the lines of `solve`.

Answer (score 0):

With Julia 0.6 this works straight out of box:

```
julia> using SymPy, Roots

julia> x = Sym("x")
x

julia> expr = sin(x)
sin(x)

julia> fzeros(expr, -10, 10)
7-element Array{Float64,1}:
 -9.42478
 -6.28319
 -3.14159
  0.0
  3.14159
  6.28319
  9.42478
```

But it's a lot slower than pure Julia solution.
Here are some benchmarks I ran with `BenchmarkTools`:

Naive Solution (6.8s):

```
fzeros(expr, -10, 10)
```

Pure Julia (1.5ms):

```
fzeros(x-> sin(x), -10, 10)
```

Semi-Naive (7.6ms):

```
fzeros(Function(expr), -10, 10)
```

Explicit Conversion (3.8ms):

```
expr2 = Function(expr)
fzeros(expr2, -10, 10)
```